# Exclude a group that contains localhost

Tags: ansible

Given the following inventory :

```
[group1]
myserver.domain.com   ansible_ssh_user=myUser

[group2]
localhost             ansible_connection=local
```

How can I only execute my playbook on the `group1` host(s) ?

When I use `--limit=group1`, it also includes localhost

I tried `--limit='!group2'`, it does not work either.

Any idea?

Thx in advance

**EDIT:**
I am using ansible 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it on your ansible version. I suggest you a workaround changing the target host definition in your playbook as follows:

So you'll have something like this

```
- name: Test limit
  hosts: "{{ hosts_nodes | default('all')}}"
  tasks:
      - file: path=/tmp/mydir state=directory
```

and running the playbook adding the additional environment variable hosts_nodes

```
ansible-playbook -i test.inventory test.yml -e hosts_nodes=group1
```

Comment: Thx again. This seems to be a good workaround but I would say ```default('none')``` instead of ```'all'```

Comment: It was just an example. Of course choose the most suitable default value to your purpose

Comment: Even if it was not exactly what I expected, I'd check this answer. I was hoping to have the reason why localhost is systematically included, even if I exclude its group ... I guess it is how ansible works... Thx for your time.

Answer (score 0):

What ansible version are you using? It works correclty in version 2.1.2.0.

This is my test.inventory file

```
[group1]
myserver.domain.com   ansible_ssh_user=myUser

[group2]
localhost             ansible_connection=local
```

This is my test playbook test.yml

```
- name: Test limit
  hosts: all
  tasks:
      - file: path=/tmp/mydir state=directory
```

I get what expected both running

```
ansible-playbook -i test.inventory --limit group2 test.yml
```

and

```
ansible-playbook -i test.inventory --limit '!group1' test.yml
```

Comment: Thx for anwsering, but you include group2 only. What I am trying to achieve is the exact oposite : include only group1.

Comment: Are you joking? Change to "--limit group1" or --limit '!group2'". Try updating Ansible version if it doesn't work.

Comment: I am not joking ... what you answered works. but not the opposite : localhost seems to be systematically included.

Comment: And I canoot update ansible version unfortunately... I wish I could.